# Customization UISegmentedcontrol and UISwitch iOS 9 in swift without installing pods

Tags: ios, swift, customization, uisegmentedcontrol, uiswitch

3 days I am searching internet for Customization UISegmentedcontrol and UISwitch iOS 9 in swift. I got switch and segmented control, so I want to implement some fancy design with images etc... but I cant find anything without installing some old cocoa pods in obj-C. Is there native way to custimizate them? some fresh new tutorial for this issue? As well, I dont want to programmatically set them.

Thanks in advance.

P.S I hope there wont be down vote :)

EDITED:

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Comment: can you show some sample which type do u need

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik done

Comment: for segment control you can use `UIbutton` for UISwitch see this http://beageek.biz/create-custom-switch-control-view-xcode-ios/

Answer (score 0):

Both UISwitch and UISegmentedControl have fairly powerful inbuilt customisation capabilities, such as allowing you to set background images, tint colour, text attributes, You can also try subclassing or extending these control for even more granular control. Try referring to these docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006784-CH3-SW7

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006807-CH3-SW33

:)

Comment: In iOS 7, this property has no effect. for image?

Comment: Specifically, which property are you talking about? And for which control?

Comment: both, this is for switch